# Calculate a percentage of two values in Zabbix

Tags: zabbix

I'm reading information from a Xerox Photocopier via SNMP, i'm trying to read the status of the toners. This machine doesn't supply this information in a percentage left but thats how i would like to display it.

For instance the current reading for the black toner is 460, there is another key for max capacity for the black toner and this is 4600. So there is 10% left of this toner.

How or where can i enter the calculation to make this work on the SNMP item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible to achieve using [calculated items](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/calculated). The first example on that page does percentage calculation based on two items. In other words, you would create a calculated item with expression similar to the following:

```
100 * (last("current") / last("total"))
```